# CefSharp browser not working as WPF screensaver on login screen

Tags: .net, wpf, inno-setup, cefsharp

### WPF screensaver that uses CefSharp fails in login screen

I wanted to create a WPF screensaver that uses CefSharp to display a website. I installed the screensaver and made all necessary changes in the registry with InnoSetup.
The changes are as follows:

```
[Registry]
Root:HKU; Subkey:".DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "SCRNSAVE.EXE"; ValueData:"{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Components: login both
Root:HKU; Subkey:".DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "ScreenSaveTimeOut"; ValueData:"30"; Components: login both
Root:HKU; Subkey:".DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "ScreenSaverIsSecure" ; ValueData:"0"; Components: login both
Root:HKU; Subkey:".DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "ScreenSaveActive"; ValueData:"1"; Components: login both
Root:HKCU; Subkey:"Control Panel\Desktop"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "SCRNSAVE.EXE"; ValueData:"{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Components: desktop both
Root:HKCU; Subkey:"Control Panel\Desktop"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "ScreenSaveTimeOut"; ValueData:"30"; Components: desktop both
Root:HKCU; Subkey:"Control Panel\Desktop"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "ScreenSaverIsSecure" ; ValueData:"0"; Components: desktop both
Root:HKCU; Subkey:"Control Panel\Desktop"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "ScreenSaveActive"; ValueData:"1"; Components: desktop both
```

The provided code is part of a .iss file.
My Problem is, the screensaver works fine on my Desktop and in my lock screen.
In the login screen however, it starts and then fails with the following two codes:

> .NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.0 - There was a failure initializing
> profiling API attach infrastructure.  This process will not allow a
> profiler to attach. HRESULT: 0x80004005. Process ID (decimal): 11004.
> Message ID: [0x2509].
>
> Application: ScreensaverWPF.scr Framework version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception information: exception code e0000008, exception address
> 00007FF9668F3E49

The codes are from the Event viewer.

I didn't add try catch statements yet. However, I tried to save .dmp files that WerFault.exe would normally create. WerFault.exe saves the .dmp files from a little script, that crashes intentionally, but doesn't create any for the screensaver. In the registry, I created a key named: `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\ScreensaverWPF.scr`

I configured the key as it is descriped in: [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps)

How can I solve this?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.Wpf;


namespace ScreensaverWPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {


        private Point mousePoint;
        private string link;

        public void InitializeChromium()
        {
            if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
            {
                CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
                Cef.Initialize(settings);
                browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();
        }


        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            link = "https://www.google.de/";
            WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;
            browser.Load(link);
        }

        private void MainWindowKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void MainWindowMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point startPoint = new Point(0,0);
            Point currenPoint = e.GetPosition(overlay);
            if (!mousePoint.Equals(startPoint))
            {
                if (Math.Abs(mousePoint.X - currenPoint.X) > 5 || Math.Abs(mousePoint.Y - currenPoint.Y) > 5)
                {
                    Application.Current.Shutdown();
                }
            }
            mousePoint = currenPoint;
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnMouseWheel_(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some try catch statements and log any exceptions to disk? I'm wondering if the exception you are seeing is obscuring the actual error.

Comment: Just isn't enough information for me to even speculate.  Are there any other screensavers that use chromium that work? Is what your attempting even possible?  See if anyone else has a chromium screen saver that works

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to make a chromium screensaver for the login screen. That's the reason why I opened this question. As mentioned above, the screensaver works fine on my desktop and in the lock screen. I can't find a post where someone implemeted a working login screensaver with chromium.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I solve this?

It seems like you need more information first, as you don't know what causes that problem.

CEF will write a file called `debug.log`. Unfortunately, in session 0 (the login screen), this file is attepted to be written in `C:\Windows\System32\debug.log`, which is inaccessible.

As a workaround you can create that file with an editor running in administrator mode. Make sure to use a 64 Bit application that is not virtualized (otherwise the file will be created in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\debug.log`.

Once the file is created, change the permissions in a way that `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE` can access it. I just granted everybody full rights like this:

[image: Everybody permissions]

Now, log out and let your screen saver run once more. Once the error message is displayed, close it and log in again. Have a look at the `debug.log`. Likely it will contain an error like this:

```
[1123/211039.508:ERROR:core_audio_util_win.cc(427)] Failed to create Core Audio device enumerator on thread with ID 10016
```

I thought this could be mitigated by turning the audio off with

```
CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("mute-audio", "true");
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

but unfortunately that didn't help.

Don't forget to delete `debug.log` after you found and fixed the issues.

Comment: For reference you can configure where the log file is created http://cefsharp.github.io/api/85.3.x/html/P_CefSharp_CefSettingsBase_LogFile.htm there are a few command line args that might be worth testing https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:media/base/media_switches.cc;l=59?q=force-wave-audio&sq=&ss=chromium and https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:media/base/media_switches.cc;l=24?q=force-wave-audio&ss=chromium would be some that I'd try